# Understand a limit relation of averages of sequences.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation, ergodic-theory

I'm studying proof in  ergodic theory about the convergence in $L^2(\mu)$ of the averages of the form  $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^NT^{p(n)}f$$ where $p(n)=n^2$ and $T^{p(n)}f=foT^{p(n)}$

Now in the proof i saw in the lecture notes this limit being used: $$\lim_{N \to +\infty}||\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^NT^{n^2}f-\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\frac{1}{[\frac{N}{r}]}\sum_{n=1}^{[\frac{N}{r}]}T^{(rn+j)^2}f||_2=0$$

Now in general if we have a bounded sequence $a_n$ then can someone explain to me why $\lim_{N \to +\infty}|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_{n^2}-\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\frac{1}{[\frac{N}{r}]}\sum_{n=1}^{[\frac{N}{r}]}a_{(rn+j)^2}|=0$.

I understand that if we take $r<N$ and apply the euclidean division theorem  then we know that every natural number in $\{1,2....N\}$ has the form: $$rn+j,\text{  where  }0 \leq j<r$$.

I tried to see my self, without success,why the limit is zero by taking $r=2$.

Can someone explain me,why  this limit is zero?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the $T^{(rn+j)}$ supposed to be $T^{(rn+j)^2}$  in the first limit equation?

Comment: If $N$ is a multiple of $r$ it is easier, so then we get $$\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n^2} - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=r}^{N+r-1} a_{n^2}\right| = \frac{1}{N}\left|\sum_{n=1}^{r-1} a_{n^2} - \sum_{n=N+1}^{N+r-1} a_{n^2}\right| \leq \frac{a_{max}(2(r-1))}{N} \rightarrow 0$$ where $|a_j|\leq a_{max}$ for all $j$.

Comment: @Michael indeed it is $(rn+j)^2$..thank you for the correction